# How to solve library conflict between OpenCV libjpeg and fltkjpeg?

Tags: c, opencv, shared-libraries, static-libraries, fltk

The issue is, there is a library I have to link called fltkjpeg.lib in order to read *.jpg format.
But my application also need to link with OpenCV libjpeg.lib library.
When I link fltkjpeg library then OpenCV jpeg library doesn't work.
and when I link OpenCV jpeg , then FLTK jpeg doesn't read jpeg images.

How can I remove this conflict ?

By the way, how can I set OpenCV image data into FLTK image data ? currently I using like this Fl_Shared_Image::get(filepath);

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved in this way, It is working perfectly.

```
Oimg1 = cvLoadImage(Image1, 0);
if(Oimg1 == NULL) {return 0;}

unsigned char* imgdata1 = new unsigned char[Oimg1->width*Oimg1->height*Oimg1->nChannels];
GetImageDataFromOpenCV(Oimg1, imgdata1);
Fl_RGB_Image *rgb_img0 = new Fl_RGB_Image((const uchar *) imgdata1, Oimg1->width, Oimg1->height, Oimg1->nChannels);
FLTKimg[0] = (Fl_Shared_Image *)rgb_img0;
```